# ConfigurationChanged not getting fired in Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="LoginActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"/>
</application>
```

When the fragment/popUp is launched from Activity, and when I charge the device with the popUp open, then this attached screen comes up by default

[image: On Charge]

The activity and fragment are getting recreated. I suspect that the configuration must be changed. However OnConfigurationChanged is not getting fired in my activity.
I tried having  this overridden in the baseactivity as well, but it didn't help.

```
 [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
  public partial class LoginActivity : BaseActivity
  {
    // other code
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // To handle attaching Scanner(or Keyboard) at runtime withOUT restarting activity
    }     
  }
```

OnConfigurationChanged is not getting fired at all. I tried checking similar posts, one such post mentioned to remove portrait/landscape mode from the activity which I tried. Any suggestion on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, you do not need to registed `LoginActivity ` in `AndroidManifest`, just add `ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation| ConfigChanges.UiMode| ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden` in `[Activity(Label = "App31", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation| ConfigChanges.UiMode| ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]` above `LoginActivity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xamaring.Android, when using the `[Activity]` attributes, whatever you put in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file gets overwritten as at compile time these attributes will be looked up and a AndroidManifest.xml file will be generated. You can see the resulting one in obj/Debug/android/.

So instead as Leon suggested in the comments, add the properties needed in the `[Activity]` attribute:

```cs
[Activity(
    Label = "@string/app_name",
    Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
    MainLauncher = true,
    ConfigurationChanges =
        ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | 
        ConfigChanges.Orientation |
        ConfigChanges.UiMode |
        ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden
)]
public partial class LoginActivity : BaseActivity
{
    // other code
    public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // To handle attaching Scanner(or Keyboard) at runtime withOUT restarting activity
    }     
}
```

This will add an entry like:

```
<activity android:label="LoginActivity" android:mainLauncher="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode" />
```